# How to create a log to track the column name, old values, new values, when user updates as table in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, triggers

Hello i am tring to take a log of the column name old value and new value that is being modified.I went through the solution available but getting the errors of sql syntax. Unsure where issue actually lies.

Trigger i genrated in as below

```
CREATE TRIGGER `products_change` AFTER UPDATE ON `products`
 FOR EACH ROW in
 BEGIN
    IF NEW.name <> OLD.name THEN
        INSERT INTO product_change_logs(column_name, old_value, new_value) values ('name', OLD.name ,NEW.name);
    END IF;
END
```

Also tried information schema to loop through the column name to avoid the if else but facing the same. Request to please guide with a best approach to create the same, also way to pass the value to trigger like user_id or something.

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: It might be worth looking at: http://www.laravel-auditing.com/

Comment: It's seems very good but am using a framework in laravel and don't want to change its model as it will keep updating on updates any idea how to achieve bthat.

Comment: For what it's worth the MariaDB version of MySQL has a newish feature called System Versioning Tables.  https://mariadb.com/kb/en/temporal-data-tables/  It lets you issue queries like `SELECT * FROM t FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF TIMESTAMP'2016-10-09 08:07:06';` It automatically tracks updates / inserts / deletes.  It's worth considering to meet your requirement.  See this. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13904/how-to-enable-temporal-database-capability-in-mysql

Comment: its mysql 5.16 maria db